# How to set /sys/module/printk/parameters/always_kmsg_dump kernel parameter?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

This parameter file is set to N. How to set it to Y ? I tried changing the file but after a reboot it turns back to N.

Comment: I think that you need to compile the kernel with your own config

Comment: so.. just `echo Y > /sys/module/printk/parameters/always_kmsg_dump` as root? What have you tried?

Comment: @KamilCuk: The question is to make the parameter persistent after reboot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to set it on the [boot command line](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt):

> printk.always_kmsg_dump=
> Trigger kmsg_dump for cases other than kernel oops or panics
> Format:   (1/Y/y=enable, 0/N/n=disable)
> default: disabled